# How does one draw a graph in maxima

Tags: math, graph, polynomial-math, maxima

I dont know how to draw a graph in maxima where i need to point out (eg. points have to be seen on the graph) the local extrema and realroots. I have calculated them but I have no idea how to implement it in to the graph. This is my function:

> x^6-7*x^5+7*x^4+35*x^3-56*x^2-28*x+48

realroots:

> [x=-2, x=-1, x=1, x=2, x=3, x=4]

local extrema (x):

> [x=-0.2111865524892743,x=-1.623405772994074,x=1.457167417575563,x=2.555696242823922,x=3.655061998417197]

local extrema (y):

> -58.02141996243023,
>   51.10292971871804,
>   -8.27052172358404,
>   8.98628528970282,
>   -26.13817267082878.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: John, do I understand correctly that you want a smooth curve for your function and also distinct points overlaid on the curve?

Comment: @RobertDodier yes, but I have successfully solved this problem, with using plot2d, but now I am facing a new problem, I have to calculate the same things(roots, and extremas) for another equation which isnt a polynomial, so Maxima returns an error that realroots only works for polynomials. Any idea how to solve this problem? 
Here is the formula I have recieved: "(1/2)*(sin(5*x)−x)^2"

Comment: Take a look at `find_root`. Note that you must supply an interval to search over.

Comment: @RobertDodier thank you for the response, I used find_root like this: **find_root((1/2)*(sin(5*x)−x)^2,-4,4);** but i get an error saying **function has same sign at endpoints** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `find_root` can only find a root if the function changes sign (exactly once) on the interval. If you plot the function, do you see an interval on which the function changes sign? Try `plot2d(myexpr, [x, -4, 4]);` where `myexpr` is your function.

Comment: @RobertDodier This function does not change sign, but it touches the x axis three times, at **-0.51 , 0 , 0.51** (used wolfram-alpha for that) after that it goes upwards to infinity.

Comment: To find a minimum point, you can use `find_root` to find a root of the derivative of your function, i.e., `find_root(diff(myexpr, x), ...)`. From looking at a plot of your function, you can guess some small intervals on which to search.

Comment: @RobertDodier If I do it that way, the output is the first number i put as range, if i did it like this **find_root(diff((1/2)*(sin(5*x)−x)^2), x,-0.1,0.1);** it returns me -0.1, and if i put it -0.3, it returns -0.3

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the comment: "if i did it like this find_root(diff((1/2)*(sin(5*x)−x)^2), x,-0.1,0.1); it returns me -0.1, and if i put it -0.3, it returns -0.3".

The problem there is that you need to write `diff(..., x)`, not just `diff(...)` without the second argument `x`. Here I've tried that:

```
(%i1) e:(1/2)*(sin(5*x)-x)^2;
                                       2  
                         (sin(5 x) - x)
(%o1)                    ---------------
                                2  
(%i2) e1:diff(e,x);
(%o2)            (5 cos(5 x) - 1) (sin(5 x) - x)
(%i3) find_root(e1, x, -0.1, 0.1);
(%o3)                          0.0
(%i4) find_root(e1, x, -0.3, -0.1);
(%o4)                 - 0.2738876812009132
(%i5) find_root(e1, x, 0.1, 0.3);
(%o5)                  0.2738876812009132
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had to tweak it a bit, but i got the right roots now! But I still need to point out the local maxima and minima but the function does not touch the x axis again, how can i get the points?
this is a graph of the function https://imgur.com/a/rJSJO4B

Comment: The local minima and maxima are also roots of `diff(..., x)`. So you can find them via the same find_root as before, except with different left and right points.